# How to access a method from app.component from other component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Typescript and Angular 2.  I tried to look for an answer in the web but it seems they don't work for me.

Say I have an app.component as shown below:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public _testService: TestService) { }

    listForCart = this._testService.getListForCart();
    cartCount = this.listForCart.length;
    cartPayableAmount = 0;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.computeTotal();
    }

    TestingFunction(){
        console.log("Got here");
    }
}
```

---

Now I want to access the TestingFunction in my app.component in other class as shown below:

```
export class BuyTestComponent {

    constructor(private _testService: TestService) {
    }

    public pageTitle: string = "ALL PRACTICE TEST SERIES";

    TestHere() {
        // should call TestingFunction() here.....
    }
}
```

How to do that? Please help

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you need access to a function from several places, consider putting it in a service as @tibbus mentioned.

**utility.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UtilityService{

    TestingFunction(){}
}
```

Next, make sure the service is listed in the `providers` array of your main module:

**app.module.ts**

```
// https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#ngmodule-properties
@NgModule({ 
  imports:      [ BrowserModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, BuyTestComponent ],
  providers:    [ UtilityService ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

You can then inject that service in any component that needs access to the function

**buy-test.component.ts**

```
@Component(...)
export class BuyTestComponent {

    //inject service into the component
    constructor(private util:UtilityService){}

    TestHere() {
        //access service function
        this.util.TestingFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: It will call a function inside service not a function in app component

Comment: @Venkat that's true; On a hunch, I guessed that the OP's problem would be solved with a better architecture so I proposed a different approach altogether.  Seems I was right since my answer was accepted. If you really want to execute the method in app component, you can use Burnee's answer or store the instance of `AppComponent` in a service, so that you can access it and execute its methods from anywhere.

Comment: can i inject Buy UtilityService in to two other component classes  TestComponent1 & TestComponent2 ?

Comment: what if the method you want to call modifies properties that are part of the component that cannot be isolated into a service ? for example a variable that is used in a "*ngIf*

Answer (score 13):

Assuming your class AppCompenent is saved as app.component.ts
Then in your BuyTestComponent class, you need to first import it AppComponent like below

```
import {AppComponent} from '../app.component';
```

Assuming both files are saved in the same folder.

Instantiate it in your constructor like below

```
constructor(public myapp: AppComponent){}
```

then call it in your BuyTestComponent like below

```
this.myapp.testingFunction();
```

lastly, you need to register it as a provider in your app.module.ts

```
providers: [
 AppComponent,
]
```

Comment: It seems kinda whacky to register a component as a provider, but this seems to work

Comment: Seems to me this runs the risk of executing the function on a different instance of `AppComponent` from the one in the browser, depending on how the Dependency Injector instantiates the class. I would suggest that rather than going this route, we store `AppComponent` in a singleton (global) service inside the component's constructor or `ngOnInit`.  Once the component is a property of the service, it (and its method) can be accessed wherever the service gets injected.

Comment: you are right.. as a provider will not work for complex apps.. i did a static property that is populated on nginit..

Answer (score 4):

Angular2 has 2 ways to communicate between 2 components :

1. Via @Input / @Output if the components have Parent-Child relationship
2. Via a Service

Both ways are detailed in this article from Angular2 docs : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest way to achieve this is, basically create a static property in the app component that is populated when onInit

In app.component

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  static myapp;

 ngOnInit() {
    AppComponent.myapp = this;
 }
}
```

then in your component

```js
import { AppComponent } from '../../app.component';
export class UsersComponent  implements OnInit {

 ngOnInit() {
    console.log(AppComponent.myapp);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Events** like:

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
  constructor(public events: Events) {
    events.subscribe('myEvent', () => {
      this.myMethod();
    });
  }

  myMethod() {
    console.log("my method was activated");
  }
```

*anotherclass*

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
constructor(public events: Events) {
}

callEvent() {
  this.events.publish('myEvent');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases [BeetleJuice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40145002/how-to-access-a-method-from-app-component-from-other-component#answer-40145529) is the right solution: put the cross-component functionality into service(s).

However sometimes you have unequivocally cohesive components, which you want to connect in the parent component's HTML template.

In this case, using a service would be overhead. Luckily you can use the [template reference variables (#var)](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars)

Let's say you have a popup component:

```
// import...

@Component({
    selector: 'my-popup',
    template: '<div *ngIf="visible"><ng-content></ng-content></div>'
})
export class MyPopupComponent {
    public visible: boolean = false;
    public toggle() {
        this.visible = !this.visible;
    }
}
```

And a toggle component that can trigger a popup component to toggle:

```
// import...

@Component({
    selector: 'my-popup-toggle',
    template: '<button (click)="popup?.toggle()"><ng-content></ng-content></button>'
})
export class MyPopupToggleComponent {
    @Input('for') popup: MyPopupComponent;
}
```

Then it's so easy to connect components across the HTML:

```
<div>
    <my-popup #popup1>Good popup</my-popup>
    <my-popup #popup2>Better popup</my-popup>
    <my-popup #popup3>Best popup</my-popup>
</div>
<div>
    <my-popup-toggle [for]="popup1">Toggle the good</my-popup-toggle>
    <my-popup-toggle [for]="popup2">Toggle the better</my-popup-toggle>
    <my-popup-toggle [for]="popup3">Toggle the best</my-popup-toggle>
    <my-popup-toggle [for]="popup3">Toggle the best with another button</my-popup-toggle>
</div>
```

In very simple situations you can do something like this too:

```
<div>
    <my-popup #popup4>Best popup II</my-popup>
</div>
<div>
    <button (click)="popup4.show()">Toggle the best II</button>
</div>
```

In case you need, you can also access the template reference variable from the parent component:

```
// import...

@Component({
    selector: 'my-parent-comonent',
    template: `
        ...<my-popup #popup5>Best popup III</my-popup>...
        ...<my-popup #popup6>Best popup IV</my-popup>...
    `
})
export class MyParentComponent {
     @ViewChild('popup5') popup5: MyPopupComponent;
     @ViewChild('popup5') popup5: MyPopupComponent;
     showPopup5() { this.popup5.show(); }
     showPopup6() { this.popup6.show(); }
}
```